# C++ Control reaches end of non-void

Tags: c++, coding-style

i am trying to compile this but it gives me that annoying error.

```
Image imageLabeling(const Image &img, ImageLabels &imgL)
{

    long numLines=img.size();
    long numCols=img[0].size();

    int u=0;
    int v=0;
    int label=1;

    imgL.resize(numLines);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        imgL[i].resize(numCols);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i <numLines; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=0; j <numCols; j++)
            imgL[i][j]=0;


    for (int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++)
        {
            if(img[i][j]=='1'&&imgL[i][j]==0)
            {
                floodFill (u,v,label,img,imgL);
                label++;
            }
        }}
```

Any ideas?

P.s this is my hole code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream> //NOTE: needed to use files
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Create a new type and call it 'Image'
typedef vector<vector<char>> Image;
typedef vector<vector<int>> ImageLabels;
//============================================================
// Reads an image from input stream 'f'
// 'f' can be a previously open text file or 'cin'
// and stores it into 'img'
//------------------------------------------------------------



void readImage(istream &f, Image &img)
{
    unsigned int numLines, numCols;

    cout << "Number of lines ?"<<endl;
    f>>numLines;
    f>>numCols;
    cout << "Number of columns ?"<<numCols<<endl;


    img.resize(numLines);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        img[i].resize(numCols);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i <numLines; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=0; j <numCols; j++)
            f >> img[i][j];
}

void readCompFile (istream &f, Image &img) //
{
    int row=0;
    int cols=0;
    char value ='0';
    f>>row;
    f>>cols;
    f>>value;
    int numPixels=0;
    vector<char> tmp;
    while(f>>numPixels)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<numPixels;i++)
        {
            tmp.push_back(value); // insere continuamente no vector tmp os valores do formato comprimido
        }
        if (value=='0')
            value='1';
        else
            value='0';
    }

    for(int i = 0;i<row;i++)
    {
        vector<char> accumulator;
        for(int j=0;j<cols;j++)
        {
            accumulator.push_back(tmp[i*row+j]); // retira os valores bin·rios da imagem, criada no vector tmp, para o vector accumulator, em linha e coluna.
        }
        img.push_back(accumulator); // retira os valores do vector acumulator, para a imagem final apresentada na consola.
    }
}

void showImage(ostream &f, const Image &img)
{
    for (unsigned int i=0; i <img.size(); i++)
    {
        for (unsigned int j=0; j <img[i].size(); j++)
            f << setw(3) << img[i][j];
        f << endl;
    }
}

void floodFill (int u, int v, int label,Image img, ImageLabels &imgL)

{
    struct Point { int x; int y;} p;


    u = p.x;
    v = p.y;

    vector <Point> stack;
    stack.push_back(p);


    while (!stack.empty())
    {
        stack.back ();
        stack.pop_back();

        u = p.x;
        v = p.y;
        //u=u+1;

        Point one = {(u+1), v};
        Point two = {u,(v+1)};
        Point three = {u,(v-1)};
        Point four = {(u-1),v};

        if ((u>=0) && (u<img.size()) && (v>=0) && (v<img[0].size()) && img[u][v]==1)
        {
            stack.push_back(one);
            stack.push_back(two);
            stack.push_back(three);
            stack.push_back(four);
        }
    }
}

void readImageLabeling(istream &f, Image &img)
{
    unsigned int numLines, numCols;

    f>>numLines;
    f>>numCols;


    img.resize(numLines);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        img[i].resize(numCols);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i <numLines; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=0; j <numCols; j++)
            f >> img[i][j];
}


//============================================================
// Writes an image 'img' to output stream 'f'
// 'f' can be a previously open text file or 'cout'
//------------------------------------------------------------


Image imageLabeling(const Image &img, ImageLabels &imgL)
{

    long numLines=img.size();
    long numCols=img[0].size();

    int u=0;
    int v=0;
    int label=1;

    imgL.resize(numLines);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        imgL[i].resize(numCols);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i <numLines; i++)
        for (unsigned int j=0; j <numCols; j++)
            imgL[i][j]=0;


    for (int i=0; i<numLines; i++)
        for (int j=0; j<numCols; j++)
        {
            if(img[i][j]=='1'&&imgL[i][j]==0)
            {
                floodFill (u,v,label,img,imgL);
                label++;
            }
        }}




Image chooseFormat(bool answer)
{
    Image imgOrg,imgComp;
    ifstream inputImg,inputImgComp;

    inputImg.open("img1.txt");
    ofstream outputImg("img2.txt");

    inputImgComp.open("img_comp1.txt");
    ofstream outputImgComp("img_comp2.txt");
    if (answer == true)
    {readImage(inputImg,imgOrg);
        showImage(cout,imgOrg);
        showImage(outputImg,imgOrg);
        return imgOrg;
    }
    else
    {
        readCompFile (inputImgComp, imgComp);
        showImage(cout,imgComp);
        showImage(outputImgComp,imgComp);
        return imgComp;
    }

}

int main()
{
    Image imgResult;
    ImageLabels imgLabel;

    bool answerFormat = false;
    string answer;
    cout<<"Read normal format?"<<endl;
    cin >> answer;
    if(answer=="yes")
        answerFormat=true;
    else
        answerFormat=false;

    imgResult=chooseFormat(answerFormat); //usa a funÁ„o answerFormat para escolher o tipo de ficheiro que se quer interpretar - imgResult
    imageLabeling(imgResult,imgLabel); // faz o labeling da imagem escolhida (normal/comprimida - imgResult)
    cout<<endl;
    showImage(cout,imgResult); // Mostra a imgResult j· etiquetada



    return 0;
};
```

Comment: The "annoying error" means that you are missing a `return` statement in your `imageLabeling` function. If it is supposed to return something, add a `return`; otherwise, make the function `void` (your code isn't using the return value of that function anyway).

Comment: Just another comment, C++ forbids using locally-defined classes with templates, as they have no linkage, so for a better portability you should declare struct Point outside the function as you are using it in STL.

Comment: @Pete Yes I know, infact I wrote... "for better portability" ...  but you are right. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

In this line:

```
Image imageLabeling(const Image &img, ImageLabels &imgL)
^^^^^
```

You are telling the compiler that your function 'imageLabeling' should return something of type 'Image'. You then go on to not actually return anything in this function.

You should change the line to read:

```
void imageLabeling(const Image &img, ImageLabels &imgL)
^^^^
```

either that or actually return the 'Image' that you promised.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not return an Image. Declare return type as void.